amCharts 5 tooltip not working after deploying on Live server
I'm absolutely new to amCharts(5), I inherited the code base,
but has to do some work.
So everything works 100% fine on my localhost, but after uploading
the code to Live site, the popup and the Legend area stopped working.
The Legend(columns names) should be clickable but they aren't and popups should be on every plot, but appearing randomly on some plots.
This is the code for the Legend which contains the popup implementation

<div id="legend_div"></div>

// PREVS_Plot - has been initiated before

//  LEGEND in OWN DIV
            let PREVS_Legend_Root = am5.Root.new("legend_div");

            let PREVS_Legend = PREVS_Legend_Root.container.children.push(
                am5.Legend.new(PREVS_Legend_Root, {
                    centerX: am5.p50,
                    x: am5.p50,
                    layout: am5.GridLayout.new(PREVS_Plot, {
                        fixedWidthGrid: true,
                        maxColumns: 4,
                    })
                })
            );



            function PREVS_Series_BASELINE(name, fieldName, stacked) {
                var PREVS_Series_to_Plot_BASELINE = PREVS_Chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new( PREVS_Plot, {
                    name: name,
                    stacked: stacked,
                    xAxis: PREVS_xAxis,
                    yAxis: PREVS_yAxis,
                    baseAxis: PREVS_yAxis,
                    valueXField: fieldName,
                    categoryYField: "short_name",
                }));

                //  BASELINE STYLE BARS & TOOLTIP
                PREVS_Series_to_Plot_BASELINE.columns.template.setAll({
                    //      tooltipText: "{name}, {categoryY}:{valueX}",
                    tooltipHTML: "<p class='Tooltip_Text' style='color: #3f4444 !important;'><em>{name}</em><br><span class='Practice_Name' style='color: #3f4444 !important;'>Tooltip text & value: {valueX}</p>",
                    cornerRadiusTR: 4,
                    cornerRadiusBR: 4,
                    fillOpacity: <?php echo $Baseline_Opacity; ?>,
                    strokeWidth: <?php echo $Baseline_Stroke_Width; ?>,
                });
                PREVS_Series_to_Plot_BASELINE.data.setAll(Data_to_Plot_PREVS);

                //  Animate on load
                PREVS_Series_to_Plot_BASELINE.appear();


                //  VALUES in BARS
                PREVS_Series_to_Plot_BASELINE.bullets.push(function () {
                    return am5.Bullet.new(PREVS_Plot, {
                        sprite: am5.Label.new(PREVS_Plot, {
                            text: "{valueX.formatNumber('#.#')}%",  //  VALUE to 1 DECIMAL PLACE
//                  fill: PREVS_Plot.interfaceColors.get("alternativeText"),
                            fill: "#000000",        //  VALUE COLOUR
                            fontSize: "<?php echo $Baseline_Font_Size; ?>px",
                            fontWeight: "bold",
                            centerY: am5.p50,
                            centerX: am5.p50,
                            populateText: true
                        })
                    });
                });

                PREVS_Legend.data.push(PREVS_Series_to_Plot_BASELINE);

            }
 PREVS_Series_BASELINE("Baseline Prevalence", "first_prac_prev", false);



ok...so what debugging have you done? If you have problems with javascript tools the very first thing to do is obviously to check in the browser's console for errors? Have you done that? What did you see? There is very little point showing us code which works in one environment but not another - the code alone in those circumstances is unlikely to reveal the problem, since it's clearly possible for it to work. You have to actually do some basic error checking as a minimum.

The most likely type of issue is something different in the environment, such as a missing file, incorrect permissions, wrong/missing credentials or reference data, etc

No console or file loading errors...nothing at all.

So maybe some difference in the data loaded into it?? Look for some difference, somewhere. We don't have access to either of your environments or any of the data which feeds this chart so we can't debug this for you

I hope that someone came across similar situation and I'm looking for a more generic response, not looking for you guys to debug because all the data is displayed correctly and works as intended. Will do more debugging today

If we can't reproduce the problem or get any debugging clues it's very unlikely anyone can advise you much. Stackoverflow is all about specific issues. We're not really a troubleshooting service. That said, if it's primarily a visual display problem rather than data, then start looking for differences or problems with your CSS, maybe

Ok, so it turns out the issue ONLY related to Brave browser. It works in Chrome, Edge, Firefox and Brave(local version only). How can this happen? got no clue

So you mean that the issue is only on your live site and only when you access the live site via the Brave browser specifically? Very odd. Have you tried clearing the cache on that browser, using a new session, and so on? Just in case of some weird glitch

This library uses canvas elements to render the charts. Brave is a privacy-focused browser, and one of the things it tries to prevent, is "browser fingerprinting" using canvas. So that is most likely what's causing the problem here. Brave users will likely have to allow "fingerprinting" for your site then, for this to fully work as intended.
